# devise after_sign_in_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, nested-forms

I create a location and user at the same time in a nested model form. I want the user to be taken to the location show page for the location id that was just created. How can I do this?

I know that I can get to locations index by putting this into the applications controller

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      locations_path # <- Path you want to redirect the user to.
    end
```

I tried

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      location_path(@location) # <- Path you want to redirect the user to.
    end
```

but it gives a nil value for id. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you should have to do is

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  location_path(resource) # <- Path you want to redirect the user to.
end
```

but something more safe in case since your `resource` will most likely be a user is:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.class == User
    location_path(resource.location) 
  elsif resource.class == Location
    location_path(resource) 
  end
end
```

This will handle both resource types and this assumes that your `User` is associated with the `Location` created.

Comment: Jason, that was it. Thanks!